# Bootstrap Form.Control select populated with date string options in format 'MONTH YYYY'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React, I'm trying to display only "MONTHS" and "YEAR" like "MARCH 2020". I want to display the current month plus current year in my selection box. And I want to display till next year's current month in the dropdown list. I want to display like "March 2020".

For example, if I am choosing "MARCH 2020" I want to display till next year "March 2021". As of now, I have got all the months by using moment. Below is the code for getting all the months. Could anyone can help me with how to achieve displaying the current month plus year till next year the same month. Thanks in advance.

```
const fareMon = () => {
  const monthList = moment.months();
  const months = monthList.map(item => (
    <option key={item} value={item}>
      {item}
    </option>
  ));
  console.log("MONTHS123", monthList);
  return months;
};

return (
  <Form.Control required as="select" name="startDate">
    <option value="">Months</option>
    {fareMon()}
  </Form.Control>
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to also establish the current year and the current month, then do a loop of exactly 13 iterations, starting from the current month.

Here is a function I wrote to implement what you described. For simplicity's sake, it's not in React and doesn't use Moment (although it does use ES6).

```
const fareMon = () => {
  const monthList = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
  const now = new Date(); //right now
  const year = now.getFullYear(); //i.e. 2020
  const months = []; //holder for output
  let currentMonthIndex = now.getMonth(); //0-11, starting with today's month
  let yearsToAdd = 0; //for next year, the next, etc.
  for ( let i = 0; i < 13; i++ ){
    if ( currentMonthIndex === 12 ){
      //we've passed December
      currentMonthIndex = 0;
      yearsToAdd++;
    }
    let yearToUse = year + yearsToAdd;
    months.push( `${monthList[currentMonthIndex]} ${yearToUse}` );
    currentMonthIndex++;
  }

  return months;
};

console.log( fareMon() );
```

Hopefully that's enough to help you out and you can use the logic in your React app. I've added some inline comments to help explain what's happening at each step.

If you don't want to include the current month of next year, just change the for loop to be `i < 12` so that an extra month isn't included.

Working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/4gu58pnm/2/

Comment: Thanks much for the solution added with inline comment :)

Answer (score 2):

#### Complete solution with live React demo

---

You may use `Array.from()` to make up an array of 13 items, where each one is a date 1 month shifted from the previous:

```
const months = Array.from(
          {length: 13},
          (_,i) => {
            const dateItem = new Date()
            dateItem.setMonth(dateItem.getMonth()+i)
            return dateItem
              .toLocaleString('en-US',{month:'long',year:'numeric'})
              .toUpperCase()
          }
        )
```

***Proof of concept:***

```js
const { render } = ReactDOM,
      rootNode = document.getElementById('root'),
      { Form } = ReactBootstrap
      
const MonthList = () => {
  const months = Array.from(
          {length: 13},
          (_,i) => {
            const dateItem = new Date()
            dateItem.setMonth(dateItem.getMonth()+i)
            return dateItem
              .toLocaleString('en-US',{month:'long',year:'numeric'})
              .toUpperCase()
          }
        )
  return (
    <Form.Control as="select">
      {
        months.map(item => (
          <option 
            value={item}
            key={item}
            label={item}
          />
        ))
      }
    </Form.Control>
  )
}

render(<MonthList />, rootNode)
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" /><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/react-bootstrap@next/dist/react-bootstrap.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I am having a doubt in (_,i) may I know what that (_) is for ?
Could you please explain me?

Comment: Thank you , I got it now :)